# SQL Query comparing values in different rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table structured as follows:

```
| product_id | category_id |
| 1          | 1           |
| 1          | 2           |
| 2          | 1           |
| 2          | 2           |
| 2          | 3           |
| 3          | 1           |
| 3          | 2           |
| 3          | 3           |
| 3          | 4           |
```

So:

- product 1 is in category 1 and 2
- product 2 is in category 1, 2 and 3
- product 3 is in category 1, 2, 3 and 4
- etc...

How can I structure an SQL Query that can retrieve a list of product_ids that are in:

1. Category 4
2. OR Category 2 but not Category 3 or 4
3. OR Category 1 but not Category 2

I have tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `catalog_category_product`
WHERE category_id = 1
 OR (category_id = 2 AND category_id NOT IN (3,4))
 OR (category_id = 1 AND category_id NOT IN (2,3))
GROUP BY product_id
```

... but this is not working as hoped.

Thanks very much in advance

Sarah

Comment: You need to join the table to itself and check the Category 2 condition on the first instance and the "but not Category 3 or 4" against the second instance of the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select product_id
from t
group by product_id
having (sum(category_id = 4) > 0) 
        or
       ( sum(category_id = 2) > 0 and
         sum(category_id in (3, 4)) = 0
       ) 
        or 
       ( sum(category_id = 1) > 0 and
         sum(category_id = 2) = 0
       );
```

The expression `sum(category_id = 4)` counts the number of rows with category 4 for each product.  The `> 0` is saying that at least one such row exists.  The `= 0` is saying that there are no such rows.

Comment: Awesome solution!!

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out, should line 7 read `) or` instead of `) and` ?

Comment: (obvious question was obvious, sorry). Works a treat.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using the `IN` predicate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id
FROM table1
WHERE category_id = 4
   OR (category_id = 2
       AND
       product_id IN(SELECT product_id from table1 WHERE category_id IN(3,4)))
   OR (category_id = 1
      AND
      product_id IN(SELECT product_id from table1 WHERE category_id != 2));
```

- [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ab5ac3/6)